# I had created a package npm for test and i can't retrieve the params of my function after install it

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm-install, npm-publish

[enter image description here][1]

```
import {addTwo} from 'testrol';
console.log(addTwo('2'));
addTwo(2);

**i publish a npm package for test before publish our packages. When i install it (testrol), i can't see the params of my function when my mouse over**
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, calsuoile !

Did you export the types of your lib?

You can find more information about how to do it on [typescript publishing docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html)

Comment: Yes thanks, it works. I had too change the "export.." instead of "export default.."